# Why python is printing the correct value but returning None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have implemented a function to add digits of a number until it reaches single digit. It returns None, but prints correct answer.

```
def single_sum(n):
    print "calling function for",n
    if(n<10):
        print n
        return n
    else:
        t=0
        for i in str(n):
            t=t+int(i)
        single_sum(t)

print single_sum(12345)
```

The output i am getting is:

```
calling function for 12345
calling function for 15
calling function for 6
6
None
```

Comment: you never returned inside the else block, the results of calling `single_sum(t)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
        single_sum(t)
```

--->

```py
        return single_sum(t)
```

You're not returning anything from your function in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not returning the recursive call, it's just making it:

```
def single_sum(n):
    print "calling function for",n
    if(n<10):
        print n # << unnecessary print
        return n
    else:
        t=0
        for i in str(n):
            t=t+int(i)
        return single_sum(t) # << return the call

print single_sum(12345)
```